# NoSuchMethodException in android

Tags: android

hi guys m having an exception

nosuchmethodexception: true
when ever i click on Text Field.
Actually whenever i start my application and then clicks on that TextField it opens a SingleChoiceDialog to me. and after that i go to some other screen and when i got back onto screen and then clicks on that textfield it gives me NOSUCHMETHODEXCEPTION:TRUE
it also says could not find a method:true

please guide

Comment: can you please post the relevant code

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to answer. Please show us the actual code it's failing on.

Answer (score 0):

Yup i have solved the Issue.

due to sudden change of the Content View (Layout of Screen) all the Views were discarded from the Current this Pointer of Activity and it will not setting the onClick of textViews.

Thanks Guys..